# how do i refer to the derived type from the base class?

Tags: c#, oop

is there a keyword for the question "?" mark below or a way to achieve the same effect without using templates?

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract void Attach(? x);
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Attach(B b) {}
}

class C : A
{
    public override void Attach(C c) {}
}
```

so that:

```
var b1 = new B();
var b2 = new B();

var c = new C();

b1.Attach(b2);
b1.Attach(c); // should not compile
```

EDIT:
with templates i mean type parameters such as `Attach<T>(T x, T y)` // if we ignore that the example takes 1 argument

Comment: What is the purpose of `foo`?

Comment: *"without using templates"* - what do you call template? generics?

Comment: @Igor yes sorry. i meant Attach instead of foo. i've corrected it now

Comment: If you want type checking on the instance of Attach and need to know the passed in type from the calling code then I see no benefit or reason to create a public facing abstract method. If you have common code make that protected or private and have each overriding type implement their own Attach member.

Comment: @Igor right. but in reality i want to change the abstract method to a virtual method so that code can be shared. i guess i oversimplified

Comment: So make a protected member (or protected virtual) with the shared code. That still allows you to create public type specific members on the derived types B and C.

Comment: @Igor what would be the type, of the argument in the protected virtual Attach? can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annoyingly, no. The closest you can get is:

```
abstract class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    public abstract void Attach(T x);
}

class B : A<B>
{
    public override void Attach(B b) { }
}

class C : A<C>
{
    public override void Attach(C c) { }
}
```

This doesn't however stop someone from writing:

```
class D : A<B>
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to avoid this, you need a runtime check for `this.GetType() == typeof(T)` or similar in `A`'s constructor.

Comment: I was with you, right up to your last sentence. That's pretty much an antipattern for me.

Comment: Agreed, but there's no compile-time way to avoid that case unfortunately

Comment: That's why generics exist though!

Comment: Granted, but they have limits, and that case (of someone doing `class D : A<B>`) can't be prevented with generic type constraints

Comment: Sure, but there's already a code smell here, I just don't want to advocate for adding another one.

Comment: Yeah the whole situation is smelly, but sometimes it's necessary unfortunately -- I've had to write this code myself in the past. Needs must, as long as you're sensible with weighing up the pros and cons of a solution

Comment: @canton7 there is basically a lot of copy pasted code, and i'm looking if i could make things more generic, without making everything dynamic

Comment: @canton7 with "where", do you mean what it does, or do you want to see an example?

Comment: @symbiont You said "there is basically a lot of copy pasted code" -- I'm asing where you're referring to. My answer doesn't contain copy/pasted code.

Comment: @canton7 i wasn't referring to your answer. it's a nice answer that avoids template parameters in function headers. i was only responding to the whole situation being smelly. i am dealing with a lot of copy pasted code, in my code base

Answer (score 2):

You can make A `Generic` like so:

```
abstract class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    public abstract void Attach(T x);
}

class B : A<B>
{
    public override void Attach(B b) {}
}

class C : A<C>
{
    public override void Attach(C c) {}
}
```

Than the following does not comile

```
b1.Attach(c); // should not compile
```